# Why can you favorite your own question?

Tags: support

I have noticed, on occasion, new questions appearing with no upvotes but marked as a favorite by 1 user.  I originally thought that perhaps someone marked it as a favorite to keep an eye on it during its early life.

However, today I found that I can actually mark my own questions as favorite and now suspect that people may be marking their new questions as favorites too.

What is the actual point in marking your own question as a favorite?  You already get updated with new votes, answers and comments on your own questions.  What additional functionality does favoriting your own questions offer?

Comment: For starters, it shows up in your [Favorites list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/74333/mrlemon?tab=favorites).

Answer (score 6):

On top of keeping updated with information, I personally use favourites as a "bookmark", so I do not have to find the question, later.

The best example of this is here on meta. If I see a question that I feel addresses an issue I see, on board, I will favourite the question in order to find it quickly, when I wish to source the meta when correcting future instances of the questionable occurrence.

In short, if the user has asked a lot of questions, favouriting one can make it easier to locate that specific question, at a later date.

Unfortunetly, a question having been favourited increases its immediate value. If I see a question that has been favourited, I assume the question has been of value to at least one other user, and investigate it more before negative voting. It could be entirely possible that users are simply using this as a tactic to defend against down voting and close voting.